# Dynamic and static char array

Tags: c, arrays, string

Here are the codes of a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * cloning(char * q){
    char s[strlen(q)];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(q); i++)
        s[i] = q[i];
    return s;
}

int main(){
    char q[] = "hello";
    char *s = cloning(q);
    return 0;
}
```

After the compilation a warning appears, so I changed the returned value like this:

```
char *b = s;
return b;
```

In this way the warning can be solved. However I found that inside the function cloning(), sizeof(s) is 5, but strlen(s) is 7. And if I change char s[strlen(q)] simply to char s[5], the output is still incorrect. Can anybody explain this problem to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: char * char_array;  char_array = new char[150]; // delete [] char_array; char_array = NULL;

Answer (score 6):

`char s[strlen(q)]` is a local variable, and hence when you return its address, it results in undefined behaviour. Thus either you could use `strdup()` or `malloc()` to dynamically allocate the array, thus ensuring that the array s is available on the heap when you return from  the function. The returned array would need to be `free()`-ed as well, else it would have a memory leak :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * cloning(char * q){
    char *s = malloc(strlen(q)+1);
    // if you write char s[strlen(q)], it is defined locally, and thus on return gives an undefined behaviour
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(q)+1; i++)
        s[i] = q[i];
    return s;
}

int main(){
    char q[] = "hello";
    char *s = cloning(q);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char s[strlen(q)];` is a valid C99 variable-length array; it is not undefined behavior. What *is* invalid, however, is returning a pointer to it because it has automatic storage duration.

Comment: The OP has not specified whether he is operating on C99, so I took some artistic license, so to speak :) But thanks for that bit. I edited the answer, to free the malloc()-ed array :)

Comment: If we were to assume they were using C89 rather than C99, the VLA usage would be a *compile-time error*. It would be caught by the compiler before you could even have a chance to invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot about that! To that point, I edited my answer to include Wumpus Q. Wumbley's point too :)

Comment: The text still appears to imply that a constant-length array would not have the problem. "This type of allocation is done in compile time" is still wrong, and your text still implies that *having* a variable-length array causes undefined behavior rather than *returning* it causing that.

Comment: I'm sorry that my question was not very clear. I know how to correct this proram, but I still am confused. In this program if we change the final return value like this: char *b=s; return b; then the local value returned problem can be solved, however, after checking I found that inside the definition of cloning(), sizeof(s) is 5 (which is totally reasonable), but strlen(s) is 7. And if I change the definition of array s simply to char s[5] (because strlen(q) is 5), then strlen(s) becomes 0.

Comment: @CrazyHenry: The compiler calculates `sizeof` by looking at the definition of the array. `strlen`, on the other hand, will search through the array you pass it looking for the first NUL byte and returns the index of it. Since you're not NUL-terminating your string, `strlen` goes off the end of the array and triggers undefined behavior. `char *b = s; return b;` does nothing to make your program any more valid; it still triggers undefined behavior by returning a pointer to an object beyond its lifetime.

Comment: @icktoofay: Beat me to it :)

Comment: @CrazyHenry: C has a unique tendency that sometimes its undefined behaviour will still provide valid results, but not always. Thus, it is better to understand when such situations arise. `char *b=s; return b` is still a local variable, whose scope is lost upon returning from the function. The fact that it works on your end does not mean that the same 'hack' will work for another :)

Answer (score 3):

```
char s[strlen(q)];
```

is a variable-length array. Like a malloc'ed buffer its size is determined at runtime. Unlike a malloc'ed buffer, it ceases to exist when the function returns.

Answer (score 3):

multiple issues with this code:

```
char * cloning(char * q){  
    char s[strlen(q)]; // s has strlen size but needs strlen + 1 to hold \0
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(q); i++) // should copy the \0 otherwise q is not a valid string
        s[i] = q[i];
    return s;// returns the address of a local var == undef. behavior
}
```

if you want to clone a string just do strdup()

```
char* cloning(char* q)
{
  return strdup(q);
}
```

or the equivalent

```
char * cloning(char * q)
{
    char* s = malloc(strlen(q)+1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(q)+1; i++)
        s[i] = q[i];
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to allocate strlen(q)+1 space for the array, because '\0' doen't need to be considered. This program can be corrected by changing the definition of char s[] to char *s = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(q)). My confusion is that when I change char s[strlen(q)] to char s[5] the result will be different.

Comment: @CrazyHenry: Using your existing code except replacing `char s[strlen(q)];` with `char s[5];` still causes undefined behavior by returning a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration and is thus invalid. Triggering undefined behavior doesn't have to be consistent.

Comment: @CrazyHenry If you want s to point to a string comparable equal to q, then s needs a `'\0` in the same place as q.

Comment: @icktoofay Actually you can change the return value like this: char *b=s; return b; then the problem can be avoided. The program above is version 1.0. You can refer to my comment in the previous answer. Sorry I didn't declare the question very clearly.

Comment: @CrazyHenry: `char *p = s;` will make a new pointer, `p`, pointing to the object `s`. Then you return `p`. The lifetime of `s` ends, and now `p` is left pointing to an object after its lifetime has ended. You are still triggering undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this with standard C, no matter version of the C standard, is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* cloning (const char* str)
{
  char*  clone;
  size_t size = strlen(str) + 1;

  clone = malloc(size);
  if(clone == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  memcpy(clone, str, size); 

  return clone;
}

int main(){
    char original[] = "hello";
    char* clone = cloning(original);

    if(clone == NULL)
    {
      puts("Heap allocation failed.");
      return 0;
    }

    puts(clone);

    free(clone);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Wolf You'll have to add some error handling in main... ok I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic arrays in C are declared using Malloc and Calloc. Try googling it.

Eg:

```
 char *test;

    test = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*Multiply_By);
```

Comment: Right, but does this answer the actual question?

Answer (score -1):

In C，static array is in stack,after function return,it's been destoryed. and string with char has a '\0' end. But strlen don't include it. For example.`char q[] = "hello"; strlen(q) = 5,but the real size is 6`
If you want to copy a string, the last '\0' must be added at the end.or using

`char *s = malloc(sizeof(q)); ...; for(i = 0; i < sizeof(q); i++)
       s[i] = q[i];`

you also need to free it after using.Maybe become a mem leak.

Hope this can help u.

Comment: -1: Byd advice because `sizeof` will return `4`. Just try it!